# Music Service doesn't play

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have created a MusicService in my app, started the service and it doesn't play.
I have started the service from my main menu, and added it(the Service) to the manifest,
i have read several posts about it and none has helped so far.(it extends service)

```
class MusicService extends Service {
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(100, 100);
}

@Override

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    else if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
    {
        mediaPlayer.stop();

    }
    return 1;
}
```

and the call from the Main Screen:

```
Intent music = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
startService(music);
```

and the service declaration on the manifest:

```
<service
     android:name="com.example.trviaForBagrut.MusicService"
     android:enabled="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this link, [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context), android.net.Uri), you must not call prepare when yoyu use the create method.

> Convenience method to create a MediaPlayer for a given Uri. On success, prepare() will already have been called and must not be called again.

Perhaps you can also use something like

```
public void setOnPreparedListener (MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener listener)
```

as you shouldn't call start unless the mediaplayer is prepared first as that could result in illegalstateexception.

Comment: I changed and added the SetOnPreparedListener,and it still doesn't play the music

Comment: Did you remove the mediaPlayer.prepare() ?

Comment: Yes I have removed the mediaPlayer.prepare();